# Checking if a surface in $\mathbb{R^3}$ exists if the first fundamental form is given

Tags: differential-geometry

Given the first fundamental form and the shape operator: $$g = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & \cos^2(u)
\end{pmatrix} \text{and} \,S = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix},$$ I want to check, if there exists a surface $f: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R^3}$ satisfying these conditions. We know that $S^T = bg^{-1},$ where $b$ is the second fundamental form. Thus, $S = I = bg^{-1}$ and $b = g.$ From here we find, $E = 1, F = 0, G = \cos^2(u), e = 1, f=0, g = \cos^2(u).$ We may also find that the mean curvature is $H=1$ and the Gauss curvature, $K = 1,$ the principal curvatures being $K_1 = K_2 = 1.$ How can I go from here to eventually find a parametrization of the surface?

Comment: that may not be exactly what you want, but the surfaces of constant curvature are well known....

Comment: Thanks. I thought first, it would be a sphere, but can not find an explicit parametrization. Can you help ?

Comment: It sure looks like a variant of spherical coordinates to me.

Comment: Spherical coordinates
\begin{align}
x&=\cos\varphi\sin\theta\,,&y&=\sin\varphi\sin\theta\,,&z=\cos\theta
\end{align}
become with $u=\theta+\frac\pi 2$  
\begin{align}
x&=\cos\varphi\cos u\,,&y&=\sin\varphi\cos u\,,&-z=\sin u
\end{align}
which should be your parametrization.

Comment: Thanks. With this proposal of change of parameters, the metric tensor is alright, but not the shape operator. I was rather looking for a formal procedure, by maybe integrating. An Ansatz seems to me rather arbitrary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your last comment that the shape operator is not alright.

It does seem alright.

As we know we have in traditional spherical coordinates
\begin{align}
f(\varphi,\theta)&=\pmatrix{\cos\varphi\sin\theta\\\sin\varphi\sin\theta\\\cos\theta}\,,&
f_\varphi&=\pmatrix{-\sin\varphi\sin\theta\\\cos\varphi\sin\theta\\0}\,,&
f_\theta&=\pmatrix{\cos\varphi\cos\theta\\\sin\varphi\cos\theta\\-\sin\theta}\,,\\[2mm]
E&=\langle f_\theta,f_\theta\rangle=1\,,&F&=\langle f_\varphi,f_\theta\rangle=0\,,&G&=\langle f_\varphi,f_\varphi\rangle=\sin^2\theta\,,\\[2mm]
f_{\varphi\,\varphi}&=\pmatrix{-\cos\varphi\sin\theta\\-\sin\varphi\sin\theta\\0}&f_{\varphi\,\theta}&=\pmatrix{-\sin\varphi\cos\theta\\\cos\varphi\cos\theta\\0}\,,&f_{\theta\,\theta}&=\pmatrix{-\cos\varphi\sin\theta\\-\sin\varphi\sin\theta\\-\cos\theta}\,,\\[2mm]
L&=-\langle f_{\theta\,\theta},\mathbf{n}\rangle=1\,,&M&=-\langle f_{\varphi\,\theta},\mathbf{n}\rangle=0\,,&N&=-\langle f_{\varphi\,\varphi},\mathbf{n}\rangle=\sin^2\theta
\end{align}
where we use that the normal vector is just
$\mathbf{n}=f(\varphi,f_\theta)\,.$
Then the shape operator is
$$
S=\pmatrix{L&M\\M&N}\pmatrix{E&F\\F&G}^{-1}=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}
$$
Switching to $u=\theta+\frac\pi2$ leads to $\sin\theta\to-\cos u$ and $\cos\theta\to\sin u$ so that in those coordinates
\begin{align}
f(\varphi,u)&=\pmatrix{-\cos\varphi\cos u\\-\sin\varphi\cos u\\\sin u}\,,&
f_\varphi&=\pmatrix{\sin\varphi\cos u\\-\cos\varphi\cos u\\0}\,,&
f_u&=\pmatrix{\cos\varphi\sin u\\\sin\varphi\sin u\\\cos u}\,,\\[2mm]
E&=\langle f_u,f_u\rangle=1\,,&F&=\langle f_\varphi,f_u\rangle=0\,,&G&=\langle f_\varphi,f_\varphi\rangle=\cos^2u\,,\\[2mm]
f_{\varphi\,\varphi}&=\pmatrix{\cos\varphi\cos u\\\sin\varphi\cos u\\0}&f_{\varphi\,u}&=\pmatrix{-\sin\varphi\sin u\\\cos\varphi\sin u\\0}\,,&f_{u\,u}&=\pmatrix{\cos\varphi\cos u\\\sin\varphi\cos u\\-\sin u}\,,\\[2mm]
L&=-\langle f_{u\,u},\mathbf{n}\rangle=1\,,&M&=-\langle f_{\varphi\,u},\mathbf{n}\rangle=0\,,&N&=-\langle f_{\varphi\,\varphi},\mathbf{n}\rangle=\cos^2 u
\end{align}
and again
$$
S=\pmatrix{L&M\\M&N}\pmatrix{E&F\\F&G}^{-1}=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}\,.
$$